# Terminate a python script using an exit code, but does not exit and gives an error code instead

Tags: python, if-statement, exit-code

Here is my code for the exit statement

```
            if "shutdown" in query:
            speak("Ok, See you")
            sys.exit(0)
```

These are the modules I have:

```
    from googlesearch import search
    import pyttsx3
    import datetime
    import wikipedia
    import pywhatkit
    import webbrowser
    import speech_recognition
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import sys
```

When I execute the command, I get this error code

```
    Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function catch_errors.<locals>.call_with_this at 0x0000020FBDAE5C60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adith.LAPTOP-K9TNBR9N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_comobject.py", line 97, in call_with_this
  File "C:\Users\adith.LAPTOP-K9TNBR9N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1505, in error
  File "C:\Users\adith.LAPTOP-K9TNBR9N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1734, in isEnabledFor
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please let me know if you need any more information.
I have tried doing `exit()` `sys.exit()` `os.exit()`. Nothing worked, I keep getting the same error codes no matter what I try.

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), and please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why do you think it is the `exit` statement causing this exception?  How did you create `speak`?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Sorry about that! I fixed it.

Comment: @TimRoberts because if I remove the exit statement and just say "shutdown" it says "Ok, see you". But with the exit command it gives me an error code.

Comment: I got speak by using pyaudio

Comment: I don't understand why you are in a COM callback.  Where is this code?  How is it called?

Comment: The code you've provided is not a minimal, reproducible example. Please edit your post to contain such information.

Comment: This code is called when I say, "shutdown". I am using the speech recognition module to call the code.

Comment: You have a `TypeError`. Your code isn't reaching your `sys.exit(0)` You'll need to provide the relevant code. Edit: Nevermind, see Tim's comment below :-) -- But we still don't have the code necessary to reproduce this.

Comment: @sytech -- Actually, it IS reaching the `sys.exit` call.  This is a callback, and the callback is catching and ignoring the exception that `sys.exit` raises.  The TypeError comes later.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I don't think I understand you, the code that I have provided is minimal and it is able to be reproduced.

Comment: When running your code, I get a `SyntaxError`, because you can't have an `elif` without an `if` statement beforehand. Have you read the page I linked about how to make a reproducible example?

Comment: @AdithyaSrivathsa, we cannot run the code you have up there.  It is a tiny snippet of a much larger program.  That's what he means by "reproducible".

Comment: Oh ok, please visit this link for the whole project code: https://github.com/AdithyaSrivathsa/Tony-AI

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find a different way to do this.  Your callback is being called from C++ code.  That code is trapping all exceptions, because the C++ code doesn't know how to pass through exceptions.  `sys.exit(0)` works by raising an exception.  The C++ code traps and ignore that exception, but `sys.exit` has already begun a shutdown, so when your code gets back to the logging module, stuff isn't there.

You'll need to set a flag in your callback that other code in your app checks, and do the shutdown that way.

### Followup

So, you have everything in a big `while True` loop.  You just need a flag:

```
    running = True
    while Running:
```

Then

```
            elif "shutdown" in query:
                speak("Ok, See you")
                running = False
```

HOWEVER, the fact that you have two nested `while` loops makes that more complicated.  I don't understand why you have the nested loops instead of one big loop, and I suggest you rewrite it to have one loop instead.

Comment: How do I do that? I am sorry if this question is stupid. But I am a complete beginner.

Comment: Without seeing the whole program, there's not a lot we can do.  We don't know what speech recognition app you're using and how it relates to your application.

Comment: Please visit this link for my whole code: https://github.com/AdithyaSrivathsa/Tony-AI

Comment: the idea of providing a minimal, reproducible example instead of the whole code is to facilitate the task for people wanting to help you. Whatever you post should be able to run by itself.

Comment: I still get the same error code

Comment: @TimRoberts Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: Have you changed anything?  The git is the same.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have updated the git

Comment: I don't like providing answers to obvious problems, especially when I told you that the nested loops were going to be a problem.  Look what happens when you do "shutdown".  It sets the flag, but you're still inside an infinite `while True` loop.  You either need to add a `break` or make the inner loop `while running:` as well.